# localStorage not storing more than one piece of data

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to store multiple pieces of data in localStorage. However, only one piece is being stored and I can't figure out why. Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
<script>
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
    localStorage.getItem("lastname");
}
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Jones");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = 
    localStorage.getItem("lastname");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome Developer tools, under the application tab "Jones" is stored but "Smith" is not. I have checked similar questions, but none seem to provide a specific solution.

Comment: It's a key value storage. If you provide second value to same key it'll override the previous one. If you want to store multiple value then store as comma separated against same key or use a different key altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You're **overwriting** `lastname` every time you call `setItem`, so the last one (saving `"Jones"`) wins.

If you want to save more than one item, either:

1. Use a different key (`lastname1`, `lastname2`, ...), or
2. Store a string in some format you can parse into individual items, for instance an array that you `JSON.stringify` when storing and `JSON.parse` when loading

---

Side note: Sadly, that `typeof` check is not adequate to determine whether you can use `localStorage`, because on some browsers in private browsing mode, `typeof` will say it's there but it'll throw an error when you try to save something. The only way to know for sure is to actually try to save something:

```
// Once on page load
const canUseStorage = typeof localStorage !== "undefined" && (() {
    const key = "_test_storage";
    const now = String(Date.now());
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(key, now);
        const flag = localStorage.getItem(key) === now;
        try {
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        } catch (e) {
        }
        return flag;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
})();

// Then use `canUseStorage` as necessary to decide if you can use it
```

(Also note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function. No need for parens around its operand.)